# How do I install a FlatPak for a specific user?

Tags: software-installation, flatpak

Let's say I'm logged on to Linux as `user1` and I want to install a Flatpak to `user2`'s account. What is the command? These do not work.

```
flatpak install --user user2 flathub com.skype.Client
sudo flatpak install --user user2 flathub com.skype.Client
```

Do I have to log on to `user2`'s account and then issue the command

`flatpak install --user flathub com.skype.Client`

or is the proper command something else? [The current documentations](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html) doesn't provide examples of the `--user` argument in use so I'm left to guess.

Comment: @user535733 Virtually every Linux server allows for a user to become another user. There are many security configurations you can use to change which users get access to which permissions and groups, but becoming other users is a fundamental feature of Unix/Linux permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the common Linux command Substitute User (`su`) or the Substitute User Do (`sudo`) command. Here are examples:

#### Installing a FlatPak with su

```
su user2 -c flatpak install --user com.skype.Client
```

You will be asked for the password of user2 to become that user.

#### Installing a FlatPak with sudo

```
sudo -u user2 flatpak install --user com.skype.Client
```

Assuming you are an admin user or a user that has "sudoer" rights, you will be asked for *your* password in which case you will then become user2 to run the command.

#### Step-by-step

You can also combine the two by becoming root first and then becoming another user:

```sh
sudo -s    # you will become root
whoami     # will print root
su user2   # you will become user2
whoami     # will print user2
flatpak install --user com.skype.Client
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I explicitly want to use the `--user` argument, so the Flatpak will only be installed on `user2`'s account. How do you add this `--user` argument to your commands above? It appears your commands would install the Flatpak to all users.

Comment: The commands are the same but simply append the `--user` option to the `flatpak install` command. The `--user` option specifies that the flatpak will be installed as the current user instead of for the entire system.

Comment: @stackinator I have edited my answer to be more specific.

Comment: may I add to use `sudo -u user2 -H` ? -H force the command to be run from user2 home directory and not from your directory. Maybe it's not relevant for flatpak but I've seen script fail because they try to write in the current directory and as user2 they don't have permissions to do so.